# Making HTTP request using Swift on OpenWhisk?

Tags: swift, openwhisk, serverless-architecture

How can I make HTTP requests to retrieve and return data during a serverless Swift function running on Apache OpenWhisk?

Serverless cloud platforms restrict access to the runtime environment. This means you can't install extra libraries to help with this, e.g https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift runtime on Apache OpenWhisk does provide the following libraries pre-installed:

- [CCurl](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/CCurl) (0.2.3)
- [Kitura-net](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-net) (1.7.10)
- [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) (15.0.1)
- [IBM Watson SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk) (0.16.0)

The `Kitura-net` library provides a higher-level API for making HTTP requests than Swift's networking primitives ([URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)).

Here's an example of using that library to return data from an external JSON API as the function response.

```
import KituraNet
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

func httpRequestOptions() -> [ClientRequest.Options] {
  let request: [ClientRequest.Options] = [ 
    .method("GET"),
    .schema("https://"),
    .hostname("api.coindesk.com"),
    .path("/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
  ]

  return request
}

func currentBitcoinPricesJson() -> JSON? {
  var json: JSON = nil
  let req = HTTP.request(httpRequestOptions()) { resp in
    if let resp = resp, resp.statusCode == HTTPStatusCode.OK {
      do {
        var data = Data()
        try resp.readAllData(into: &data)
        json = JSON(data: data)
      } catch {
        print("Error \(error)")
      }
    } else {
      print("Status error code or nil reponse received from App ID server.")
    }
  }
  req.end()

  return json
}

func main(args: [String:Any]) -> [String:Any] {
  guard let json = currentBitcoinPricesJson() else {
      return ["error": "unable to retrieve JSON API response"]
  }

  guard let rate = json["bpi"]["USD"]["rate_float"].double else {
    return [ "error": "Currency not listed in Bitcoin prices" ]
  }

  return ["bitcoin_to_dollars": rate]
}
```

HTTP requests can be still be manually made using Swift's low-level networking primitives.